# ODOO V10 how to link picking to sales invoice?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo-10, odoo

can anybody help with inf how to add link of picking to sales invoice? Customer needs to print picking nr to sales invoice lines. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Each `stock.picking` object has a One2many field, `move_lines`, pointing to `stock.move`. Each `stock.move` object has a Many2one field, `procurement_id`, pointing to `procurement.order`. And each `procurement.order` object has a Many2one field, `sale_line_id`, pointing to `sale.order.line`.

So you should create a computed field in `sale.order.line` which gets the picking, this way:

```
@api.depends('procurement_ids', 'procurement_ids.move_ids',
             'procurement_ids.move_ids.picking_id')
def _compute_picking_nbr(self):
    for line in self:
        moves = line.procurement_ids.move_ids
        if moves:
            line.picking_nbr = moves[0].picking_id
        else:
            continue

picking_nbr = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='stock.picking',
    string='Picking number'
    compute='_compute_picking_nbr'
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much forvas por your response.

Comment: You're welcome @Bakartxo. Did it answer your question? If so, set the answer as the right one to close the question, please.